# How do you Implement a Google AdMob Native Template Ad in SWIFT/Xcode/IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've been using all the instructions on Google AdMob. I downloaded and added the required zip file of native ad templates to my code.

I'm not sure how/where to add the objc code that they have provided on the site and how/where to implement this code using swift.

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the code they give:

```
/// Step 1: Import the templates that you need.
#import "NativeTemplates/GADTSmallTemplateView.h"
#import "NativeTemplates/GADTTemplateView.h"
...

// STEP 2: Initialize your template view object.`GADTSmallTemplateView *templateView =   [[GADTSmallTemplateView alloc] init];

// STEP 3: Template views are just GADUnifiedNativeAdViews
_nativeAdView = templateView;
nativeAd.delegate = self;

// STEP 4: Add your template as a subview of whichever view you'd like.
// This must be done before calling addHorizontalConstraintsToSuperviewWidth.
// Please note: Our template objects are subclasses of GADUnifiedNativeAdView so
// you can insert them into whatever type of view you’d like, and don’t need to
// create your own.
[self.view addSubview:templateView];

// STEP 5 (Optional): Create your styles dictionary. Set your styles dictionary
// on the template property. A default dictionary is created for you if you do
// not set this. Note - templates do not currently respect style changes in the
// xib.

NSString *myBlueColor = @"#5C84F0";
NSDictionary *styles = @{
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyCallToActionFont : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0],
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyCallToActionFontColor : UIColor.whiteColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyCallToActionBackgroundColor :
        [GADTTemplateView colorFromHexString:myBlueColor],
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeySecondaryFont : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0],
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeySecondaryFontColor : UIColor.grayColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeySecondaryBackgroundColor : UIColor.whiteColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyPrimaryFont : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0],
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyPrimaryFontColor : UIColor.blackColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyPrimaryBackgroundColor : UIColor.whiteColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyTertiaryFont : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0],
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyTertiaryFontColor : UIColor.grayColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyTertiaryBackgroundColor : UIColor.whiteColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyMainBackgroundColor : UIColor.whiteColor,
    GADTNativeTemplateStyleKeyCornerRadius : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:7.0],
};

templateView.styles = styles;

// STEP 6: Set the ad for your template to render.
templateView.nativeAd = nativeAd;

// STEP 7 (Optional): If you'd like your template view to span the width of your
// superview call this method.
[templateView addHorizontalConstraintsToSuperviewWidth];
[templateView addVerticalCenterConstraintToSuperview];
```